# I want a user defined function for sorting a indexed array:

Tags: php

I have to sort this array by creating a user defined function

```
$a = array(7,5,12,8,9);

function  asc($a){

    for (i = 0;i<=$a[];i++){

      /* check the element to be minimum */

      for (j = i+1;j<$a[];j++){
         if ($a[j] < $a[min]){ then
            min = j;
      }
    }

  /* swap the minimum element with the current element*/
    if (indexMin != i){
       echo $a[min] and $a[i];
    }
}
asc($a);
```

Comment: Learn about different [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). I believe you're trying to do [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $array=array('2','4','8','5','1','7','6','9','10','3');

echo "Unsorted array is: ";
echo "<br />";
print_r($array);


for($j = 0; $j < count($array); $j ++) {
for($i = 0; $i < count($array)-1; $i ++){

    if($array[$i] > $array[$i+1]) {
        $temp = $array[$i+1];
        $array[$i+1]=$array[$i];
        $array[$i]=$temp;
    }       
}
}

echo "Sorted Array is: ";
echo "<br />";
print_r($array);
```